# Why do I get an error from my API but only when I use some requests?

Tags: python, api

I am using an API from this site https://dev.whatismymmr.com, and I want to specifically request for the `closestRank` but I just get a `KeyError: 'ranked.closestRank'`. but I can get the entire `['ranked']` object (which contains the `closestRank`) but I just end up with a lot of information I don't need.

How can I end up with just the Closest rank?

My code

```
import requests 
LeagueName = input ("Summoner name")
base = ("https://eune.whatismymmr.com/api/v1/summoner?name=")
Thething = base + LeagueName
print (Thething)
response = requests.get(Thething)
print(response.status_code)
MMR = response.json()
print (MMR['ranked.closestRank'])
```

The API command
`<queue>.closestRank` (the queue is the game mode, it can be **normal** or **ranked**)
you can use the summoner name **babada27** for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for -

change The last line to

```
print (MMR["ranked"]["closestRank"])
```